# How would i get the song title from an arraylist method?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-mediaplayer

So in short, how would i modify the following sample code in order to receive just the song title, and not the entire file name? Currently, `songTitle` refers to the name of the file, and not the name of the individual song title.

Here's the method...

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){

    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }

    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/Music");
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Comment: Don't store derived properties of the filename in a `HashMap<String, String>` - write a class with fields for the title, path etc.

Comment: So is there no way of getting the individual song title just from this method?

Comment: How are the "name of the file" and "individual song title" different? Can you post an example of the output you are getting versus the output you want? It looks like this method already takes a substring of the file name, which I assume is truncating the "file" parts off to just leave the song title. So how is it coming out wrong?

Comment: Ah, yes, for certain songs however it displays the artists, or album name's first, which is why i would rather replace the file name with just the song title.

Comment: Please post the code where you are fetching the songs from ?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch all the songs in the sd card or only from a selected folder?

Comment: All the songs in the `/sdcard/Music` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan to fetch all songs stored on the SD card, you can try  using -

```
 cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Iterate over the cursor and then fetch the title using  -

```
    column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE);
cursor.getString(column_index)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i just wanted to extract the song title and not the actual file name. Something where i could use `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);`, possibly.